# Lack of Momentum exchange between photons upon apparent coalition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, wave-particle-duality

When two light beams made up of photons collide, say at an angle, in the same plane, they do not impart any momentum to the photons in each other.

But, momentum is imparted by the same photons on matter like electrons.

So, why not momentum tranfer on photons of another beam but on matter?

I made an assertion that, since, photons are particles of energy, while electrons on a surface(pocessing wave like nature) are particles of matter, therefor some difference has arisen.

Please entlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxwell's equations for electromagnetism are *linear* so if only photons are involved they cannot interact and exchange momentum.

Once we  we include interactions with virtual electrons that emerge from the vacuum, however, then
photons can interact with these electrons    and exchange momentum. This process is called  [Delbrück scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delbr%C3%BCck_scattering).  It  is hard to see because  it occurs only at fourth order in QED perturbation theory and  as a consequence one needs very intense fields.
[Light-light scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics)   has however [been detected](http://home.cern/news/news/physics/atlas-observes-light-scattering-light) at by the  ATLAS collaboration   in 2019.